# Подсчитать дубликаты в строке codewars

Tags: c#, dict, структуры-данных

Задача: Write a function that will return the count of distinct case-insensitive alphabetic characters and numeric digits that occur more than once in the input string. The input string can be assumed to contain only alphabets (both uppercase and lowercase) and numeric digits.

Идея:Идём по строке и кидаем каждый символ в словарь, если вдруг встречаем повторяющийся,то увеличиваем счётчик повторений то есть value поле для символа, затем проходим по словарю и если встречаем символ который встретился больше одного раза увеличиваем счётчик дубликатов

Код:

```
private static int CountDuplicates(string str)
        {
            /*
            Идём по строке и кидаем каждый символ в словарь, если вдруг встречаем повторяющийся,
            то увеличиваем счётчик повторений то есть value поле для символа, затем проходим по словарю и если встречаем символ
            который встретился больше одного раза увеличиваем счётчик дубликатов
            */
            int numberOfDuplicates = 0;
            var characters = new Dictionary<char,int>();
            foreach(var c in str.ToLowerInvariant())
            { 
                if (characters.ContainsKey(c))
                {
                    characters[c] += 1;
                    continue;
                }
                characters.Add(c, 1);
            }
            foreach (var c in characters)
            {
                if (c.Value > 1)
                {
                    numberOfDuplicates++;
                }
            
            }
            return numberOfDuplicates;
        }
```

Не могу дописать метод потому как не знаю как толком работать с Dictionary, смотрел на metanit'e руководство, но там не нашёл того что нужно мне. К примеру как увеличить value у конкретного ключа который нам уже встречался, это я про if, а также не совсем уверен что верно добавляю в словарь новый символ и также не знаю как дальше дописать проверку на то сколько раз в словаре записан каждый символ чтобы подсчитать сколько у нас дубликатов, и при всём при этом метод должен быть регистронезависимым

Comment: `characters[str[i]] += 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //берем строку и переводим в нижний регистр
    var str = "some String".ToLower();
    
    // создаем и заполняем дикшинари правильными символами указанными в задаче
    var characters = new Dictionary<Char,int>();
    
    foreach (var ch in "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".ToCharArray()) 
    {
        characters[ch] = 0;
    }
    
    // считаем вхождения символов
    // я умышленно не делал проверку на неправильные символы
    foreach (var ch in str.ToCharArray() ) {
        characters[ch] += 1;
    }
    
    // считаем запрошенное - количество дубликатов
    var result = characters.Where(a => a.Value >= 2).Count();
```

простой и легкочитаемый код.

Но не самый быстрый.

Вообще можно все уместить в одну цепочку линка только тогда код будет еще медленнее практически наверняка:

```
var result = "some String".ToLower()
             .ToCharArray()
             .GroupBy(x => x)
             .Where(g => g.Count() > 2)
             .Count();
```

этот код бонусом работает вообще со всеми символами а не только буквами и цифрами.

Плюс читаемость еще выше.